# First order linear differential equation, wrong result

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation:

$y'= \frac{y}{x} + x^2$

I apply this formula:

$y(x)= e^{A(x)} \int {e^{-A(x)} b(x)  dx} $

With $a(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $b(x)= x^2$, and $A(x)$ primitive of $a(x)$.

It gives:

$y(x)= e^{log|x|} \int{ e^{-log|x|} x^2 dx }$ = $|x| - \int{ |x| \cdot x^2 dx } $

With $x>0$ it is equal to $x - \frac{x^4}{4} $

But the result is wrong, it is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^3 + c \cdot x $

What am I doing wrong? I have this problem solved on the book using a "trick" instead of using this formula. Possibly I would know what I am doing wrong and how this problem can be solved using the formula above, instead of giving another solution which doesn't follow an ordinary pattern.

Comment: You messed up the $\log$ manipulations. It should $x \cdot \int x dx$ = x^3/2 and you also forgot the implicit constants which give the other term $c x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is
$$
y(x) = e^{A(x)} \cdot \bigg ( \int e^{-A(x)} b(x) dx + C \bigg )
$$
Then computing you get
$$
y(x) = x \cdot \bigg ( \int x dx + C \bigg ) = \frac{x^3}{2} + C x 
$$
Your manipulations with the $\log$ contained many mistakes.

Comment: @blaber Do I have to assume that x>0 ? Because e^log|x| is |x|, you have replaced the absolute value of x with x.

Comment: Yes you have to assume either $x > 0$ or $x < 0$ because the solution will change depending on the sign of $x$. The way you can see this is that the differntial equation itself does not make sense at $x = 0$ and this indicates that a change in the solution will occur at this point. I implicitly assumed $x > 0$ as is often (but not always) done in these classes (depending on the level of rigor).

Answer (score 1):

At least one mistake I could find is that:

Your step after "It gives:" is incorrect.

$$e^{-\log(|x|)}=\frac{1}{|x|}$$ 
What you have written is: 
$$e^{-\log(|x|)}=|x|$$

Answer (score 1):

Want to solve the differential equation:
$$y'= \frac{y}{x} + x^2$$
First normalize the form:
$$y'+ \biggr(-\frac{1}{x}\biggr)y = x^2$$
Now we can introduce an integrating factor of $e^{\int -\frac{1}{x}dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}$.
$$\dfrac{1}{x}\biggr[y'+ \biggr(-\frac{1}{x}\biggr)y\biggr] = x$$
Integrating both sides gives us
$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{y}{x} &= \dfrac{x^2}{2}+C\\
y &= \dfrac{x^3}{2}+Cx
\end{align*}$$

EDIT: Continuing from the comments below, consider the general linear first-order equation
$$y' + f(x)y = g(x)$$
We want to find an integrating factor $\lambda (x)$ such that $\lambda (x)[y' + f(x)y] = \lambda (x)g(x)$ has an exact solution. Clearly the right hand side is integrable, so we focus on the left. In order for the left hand side to be integrable, the following must be true:
$$\dfrac{d \lambda (x)}{dx} = \lambda(x)f(x)$$
We can separate this equation find the solution:
$$\lambda(x) = e^{\int f(x) dx}$$

Comment: This is right what I meant by "the book solves it using a trick". I understand what you did here, but I don't understand why. Have you followed a particular pattern or it's just intuition?

Comment: Correct; I used the well known technique of multiplying by an integrating factor. To quote 'Mathematical Methods of Physics' by Mathews and Walker, "One can show that such factors always exist (for a first-order equation), but there is no general way of finding them." However, if you consider the *linear* first-order equation $y' + f(x)y = g(x)$, and solve for a function $\lambda (x)$ such that $\lambda (x)[y' + f(x)y] = \lambda (x)g(x)$ has an exact solution, it can be shown that $\lambda(x)=e^{\int f(x) dx}$.

Comment: See my edit above if you are still curious about this technique. I remember when I took Diff EQ last year, my teacher never showed this derivation and I was never comfortable using the integrating factor technique because it felt like such a black box.